# how to rename files in a folder with the files name in file.txt in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, rename

my code

```
import os

file1 = open('names.txt', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
path = "/home/kingj/loop/"

for line in Lines:
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        md=path + line.strip() 
        ms=path + filename
        os.rename(ms, md)
```

but I ended up with only one file. why?

Comment: What do you think your 2 nested loops do?

Comment: 80K names and 80K files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os
 
path = '/home/kingj/gipfa/mfcc_2.0_40'

files = os.listdir(path)

i = 0
pathh = "/home/kingj/Recorders/new/"
# Strips the newline character
for filename in os.listdir(pathh):
        md=pathh + files[i]
        ms=pathh + filename
        os.rename(ms, md)
        i+=1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).